# AVFoundation decode prores4444 movie with alpha channel

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset, avassetreader

I'm trying to decode a prores4444 video with alpha channel on iOS with Swift to overlay as a complex animation over a user video and to export it to his library. The AVFoundation documentation is not that great and I'm struggling to find any code examples.

When I try to use the code below with AVAssetReaderTrackOutput to decode the video I get an "AVAssetReaderOutput does not currently support compressed output" error.

```
let avAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput = AVAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput(videoTracks: [videoOverlayAssetTrack], videoSettings: outputSettings: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.proRes4444])
```

Does anyone have a clue how to read in an asset track of a prores4444 with alpha channel to use it for an instance of AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction?

Should I use another codec?

Comment: You can only decode h.264 (or h.265 on newer iOS hardware). Anything else including a simple Animation codec is not supported and will not be in the future. There are other options, you will need to look into a 3rd party solution.

Comment: See my question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47651412/7840155