# Generate video file with transparent video overlay using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am trying to overlay a video (with an alpha channel) onto an existing video.

The way to do this with ffmpeg would be a command like so:

```
ffmpeg -i face_video.mov -i curtain_test.mov -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]overlay[out]" -shortest -map [out] -map 0:1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18  output.mov
```

How would I complete this task using AVFoundation on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you cannot do that with with AVFoundation under iOS. Only 24BPP (opaque) H264 video is supported by default. See [AVFoundation decode prores4444 movie with alpha channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627605/avfoundation-decode-prores4444-movie-with-alpha-channel)

Answer (score 0):

- Install MobileFFMpeg into your XCode project using pod
  pod 'mobile-ffmpeg-full', '~> 4.3'
  https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg
- Call any FFMpeg command in following way:

  [MobileFFmpeg execute: @"-i file1.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 file2.mp4"];

Comment: 'mobile-ffmpeg-full' pod have large size when i upload my app on appstore my apps get this size?